# Using date ranges in filtered views (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have created a filtered view but need to filter columns by OR instead of AND e.g. date range in column N is 1st-20th Jan 2021 OR the date range in column T is 1st-20th Jan 2021 but this doesn't appear to be achievable without an OR custom formula. How do I modify the formula below to make it work?

=or( text(N:N, "yyyy-MM") = "2020-01", text(T:T, "yyyy-MM") = "2020-01" )

Answer (score 0):

With a filtered view, you can add a column with this formula (here in Z1)

```
=arrayformula(--(mmult({--(text(N:N, "yyyy-MM") = "2020-01"),--(text(T:T, "yyyy-MM") = "2020-01")},{1;1})>0))
```

then filter with row has 1 in column Z

[image]

### Explanation

- this formula `{--(condition1),--(condition2)}` will generate 2 columns of 1/0 depending on the result of each condition
- then `mmult ({--(condition1),--(condition2)},{1;1}` will add for each row if zero, one or two conditions are retrieved [MMULT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094292)
- finally, test if the result is greater than 0
- `--` transform boolean into 0/1

### Complement

between 1st and 20th of January 2020

```
=arrayformula(--(mmult({ 
(text(N:N, "yyyy-MM-dd") >= "2020-01-01")*(text(N:N, "yyyy-MM-dd") <= "2020-01-20"),
(text(T:T, "yyyy-MM-dd") >= "2020-01-01")*(text(T:T, "yyyy-MM-dd") <= "2020-01-20")
},{1;1})>0))
```

or

```
=arrayformula(--(mmult({(N:N >= $AB$1)*(N:N <= $AD$1),(T:T >= $AB$1)*(T:T <= $AD$1)},{1;1})>0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mike but can that be used in a filtered view? i.e. in a custom formula? Also, how do you use date ranges? It doesn't appear to be possible using the formula you have shared.

Comment: I completely changed my answer, sorry for my first misunderstanding!

Comment: Thanks so much Mike but how does that work with days of the month? I need to filter between 1st to 20th of January. Sorry for any confusion!

Comment: ok, I have added the formula in the answer

Comment: I suggest to put 1st Jan 2020 and 20th Jan 2020 in 2 cells ...